# How to apply transformation on pairs of elements in dataset api in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to feed a model samples containing images and labels. One label for each image. Furthermore, instead of feeding the images directly, I want to feed the difference of every pair of images. Note that these images came from a video, so this is why I am performing the difference. Also, I considered the second label and ignored the first one.

For this reason, I have done the following which was partially successful:

```
def _parse_function(example_proto):

    # The annotation contains the following features: timestamp; arousal; valence; liking
    features = {
        'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.float32)
    }

    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
    # This is how we create one example, that is, extract one example from the database.
    image = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
    image = tf.reshape(image, [112, 112, 3])
    label = parsed_features['label']

    return label, image

def my_flat_map(labels, images):
    label_1 = tf.slice(labels, begin=[0, 0], size=[1, 1])
    label_2 = tf.slice(labels, begin=[1, 0], size=[1, 1])

    image_1 = tf.slice(images, begin=[0, 0, 0, 0], size=[1, -1, -1, -1])
    image_2 = tf.slice(images, begin=[1, 0, 0, 0], size=[1, -1, -1, -1])

    image = image_2 - image_1
    image = tf.squeeze(image, axis=0)

    to_return = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((label_2, image_2))
    return to_return

train_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename_train).map(_parse_function)\
            .batch(batch_size=2, drop_remainder=True)\
            .flat_map(my_flat_map)\
            .batch(train_batch_size)
```

Therefore, with this way, I will be consuming every 2 images from the pipeline. In other words, I will be considering images `[image1, image2]`; `[image3, image4]` and so on... On the other hand, I want to get: `[image1, image2]`; `[image2, image3]`; then apply the transformation on them to return one image and one label. I am aware that I have to use the `window` function from [tf.data.Dataset.window](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#window) api; So I replaced `batch(batch_size=2, drop_remainder=True)` with `window(size=2, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)`, and I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops._VariantDataset'> to Tensor.
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give the stack trace for the exception, to know where exactly it happened?